# SybaseIQ: Drop Table with special character

Tags: t-sql, sap-iq, quoted-identifier

I'm trying to delete a table named `DBA.[` in Sybase IQ database. This is a wrong table which is not desired so we need to delete it. I've tried several options but not successful. Please share any workaround to drop the table, if anyone knows.

```
iqisql -Udba -P*** -Sdwhdb -w500

1> drop table dba.[
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '
' on line 2

1> drop table dba.[[]
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '[[' on line 1

1> drop table 'dba.[ '
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'dba.[ ' on line 1

1> drop table dba.[
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '\' on line 1

1> drop table 'dba.[ '
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'dba.[ ' on line 1

1> drop table 'dba.[[ '
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'dba.[[ ' on line 1

1> drop table 'dba.['
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'dba.[' on line 1

1> drop table 'dba.[['
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'dba.[[' on line 1

1> drop table dba.[
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '\' on line 1

1> drop table dba.'[ '
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '[ ' on line 1

1> drop table dba.'[[ '
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '[[ ' on line 1

1> drop table dba.'[[] '
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '[[] ' on line 1

1> drop table dba.'[[] '
2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '[[] ' on line 1
```

[image: Table Name in Database]

Comment: Did you try `[dba.[]` or `"dba.["`?

Comment: Double quotes could be used i think: `DROP TABLE dba."["`

Comment: Tried these queries but not worked  

1> drop table [dba.[]

2> go

Msg 2706, Level 11, State 0:

SQL Anywhere Error -141: Table 'dba.[' not found

1> drop table [DBA.[]
 
2> go

Msg 2706, Level 11, State 0:

SQL Anywhere Error -141: Table 'DBA.[' not found

1> drop table "dba.["

2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:

SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'dba.[' on line 1

1> DROP TABLE dba."["

2> go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 0:

SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '[' on line 1

1>

Comment: SQLAnywhere database is used as a front end to manage the IQ system catalog (notice 'SQL Anywhere in error msg) SQLAnywhere 16+ does not allow square brackets in identifiers, and the docs say an attempt to upgrade to 16+ will fail if  identifiers include square brackets, net result: I'm having trouble figuring out how the table was created in the first place. I suggest you expand the audience and post to the [SQLAnywhere forum](https://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/), mention this is an IQ database, and see if someone has any ideas (eg, update table name in system catalog?)